# Ruby difference between CSV.read() and CSV.new()

Tags: ruby, csv

Given a link to download a CSV(clicking on the link downloads the CSV instead of opening it in a browser), can I read it using `CSV.read()`? I know that I can do it using:

```
CSV.new(open(params[:ad_csv]), headers: true).each |row|
  puts row # ad dict with header value as keys
end
```

I can't read the csv like this `CSV.read(open(params[:ad_csv]), headers: true, read_timeout: 600)`

I read the documentation but it didn't clear things up for me. Hence my question, difference between `CSV.read()` and `CSV.new()`.

Answer (score 1):

`CSV.new` just initializes an instance of CSV that can be assigned to a variable and can be used to read from or write to.

Whereas `CSV.read` initializes an instance of CSV and immediately reads its content into an array. From the docs:

> Use `read` to slurp a CSV file into an Array of Arrays. Pass the `path` to the file and any `options` ::new understands.

Simplified (very simplified) `CSV.read` is implemented like this:

```
def self.read(path, *options)
  new(path, *options) { |csv| csv.read }
end
```